# Content is not allowed in prolog. strings.xml in android application

Tags: android, xml

Here is my xml, and the error i am getting is "Content is not allowed in prolog."? can anyone please tell me why? i have cleaned and rebuilt my project and nothing is working so far?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Mobile</string>
    <string name="txtUsernameStartValue"/>
    <string name="txtPasswordStartValue"/>
    <string name="LblPassword">Password</string>
    <string name="LblUsername">Username</string>
    <string name="btnLogin">Login</string>
    <string name="blankstring"/>
    <string name="lblNewUser">New User?</string>
    <string name="btnRegister">Register Now !</string>
</resources>
```

any possible answers would be awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is generated during parsing of an XML document.

So remove space before the `<?xm`

For more info see [SAX Error – Content Is Not Allowed In Prolog](http://www.mkyong.com/java/sax-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog/)

**Edit**

Also try to recreate your xml file with edits if that not work yet.

Comment: i have removed it, but no luck, it gives error still

Comment: @Arrie try to create new xml file,with edited values.

Comment: okay, that worked ? lol put as answer and i will mark it :) thanks @Giru Bhai